# Magento - create product and set dimensions in php

Tags: php, magento

I'm already creating Magento products in php. Now I want to add the product's weight and dimensions (length, width, height), so that it can be used by a shipping plugin.

For settings the weight, I found this method: $product->setWeight(1.0);
But I can't find any similar method for the dimensions.

Now my questions is: How can I set the product dimensions?

This is the code I'm using for adding a product:

```
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$product->setSku("SKU");
$product->setName("name");
$product->setDescription("description");
$product->setShortDescription("short description");
$product->setPrice(9.99);

$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setAttributeSetId(9);
$product->setCategoryIds("0");

$product->setWeight(1.0);

[...] // setting stock and tax information

$product->save();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set any attribute in the same way as you set the `weight`. Let's say the attribute code is `some_attribute` you can do this:

```
$product->setData('some_attribute', 'value_here');
//or
$product->setSomeAttribute('value_here');
```

Comment: @user2878068.  You're welcome. If this helped then accept the answer. Don't leave loose ends.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has uses Magic functions hence if the attribute is associated with a product you can simply call setATTRIBUTENAME to set its value or getATTRIBUTENAME to get its value.

So in your case if you have a attribute dimentions called width and height you can call `$product->setWidth(100)` and `$product->setHeight(50)` to set its height and weight.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I can accept only one answer, but of course yours is correct, too. So thank you very much.